# Determining points on a 3-dimensional intersection closest to the origin

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I was presented with this question in a lab:

> Use the method of Lagrange Multipliers to solve the following. Be sure to let
>   Mathematica do all the heavy lifting for you. Determine the points that lie on the intersection of the ellipsoid
>   $$ x^2+y^2+9z^2=25 $$
>   and the plane
>   $$ x+3y-2z=0 $$
>   that are closest and furthest from the origin.

Completely lost, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to minimise the distance squared from the origin, $x^2+y^2+z^2$, subject to the two conditions $ x^2+y^2+9z^2-25=0 $ and $x+3y-2z=0$. Using Lagrange multipliers means finding the stationary points of
$$ L = x^2+y^2+z^2 -\lambda(x^2+y^2+9z^2-25) -\mu(x+3y-2z), $$
considered as a function of $(x,y,z,\lambda,\mu)$, and then determining which of the extrema are actually minima and maxima.

Therefore, differentiate $L$ with respect to all five variables and solve all of these being zero for $x,y,z,\lambda,\mu$, and then plug $x,y,z$ into $x^2+y^2+z^2$ to find the minima and maxima.

Comment: Thank you. It worked exactly as you said it would.

Answer (score 0):

By subtracting the first constraint from the expression for the squared distance from the origin results in $-8z^2+25$ as equivalent to the function to be minimized, given the constraints. Thus the maximum occurs for $z=0$, and the maximum distance from the origin is five. This is almost obvious, because the first constraint defines an oblate spheroid centered on the origin, and the second constraint defines a plane through the origin. You can then use Lagrange multipliers to find the minimum, if you must. Otherwise, let me suggest the substitutions $X=x+3y$ and $Y=3x-y$. The constraint plane now passes through the Y axis, and the spheroid constraint remains rotationally symmetric about the z axis.